# AJV Json Schema Validator strange behavior

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I've upgraded my Angular project from Angular 10 to Angular 13 and with it, my AJV library from version 6.12.3 to version 8.11.0

Now I'm trying to troubleshoot some issues I'm seeing on a remote deployment with the AJV but I can't seem to be able to reproduce the errors locally no matter what settings I pass to the AJV constructor.

For example, here are my options:

```
ajvOptions: any = {
    allErrors: true,
    strict: true,
    formats: { date: true, time: true },
    allowUnionTypes: true,
    jsonPointers: true,
    unknownFormats: 'ignore',
    jsPropertySyntax: true,
  };

  ajv: any = new Ajv(this.ajvOptions); // AJV: Another JSON Schema Validator
```

Even though strict should be default with this version, I'm explicitly declaring it in the options, along with unknownFormats (which previously threw an error when used with strict).

However, I cannot get AJV to throw an error! Could something be cached?

Comment: It's hard to give any advice when you haven't provided a reproduction case.

Comment: Please provide us enough code to reproduce your problem. This must include the schema and instance data